# how to find a given string by using grep

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I read some examples from stackoverflow about this problem but none of them helped me.

I have a folder where are some sql files. What I want to do is to go through all the sql files and searching for phrase and check if it exist or not. And the main problem is to write a grep expression of this phrase.

The phrase have a pattern:

> &uniq...

(for example: `&uniq.hgk56kh/gfgtk` or `&uniqjfru5u5gggggt` and so on)

After `&uniq` could be only 21 signs, so the whole expression could have maximum 26 signs.

Do You have any idea how would I go about doing this?

My examples which did't work:

```
for f in `ls $WORKDIR/*.sql`
do
if [ $(grep '[&uniq.*]\{1,26}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -w '[&uniq.*{1,26}]' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '[&uniq.[[:alnum:]]{1,26}}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '&uniq.[[:alnum:]]{1,26}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '&uniq.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,26}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '[&uniq.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,26}]' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -w '[&uniq.[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,26\}]' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -w '[&uniq.*\{1,26\}]' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -w '[&uniq.*}\{1,10\}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '[&uniq.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,26}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '[&uniq.*{1,26}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '&uniq.*'{1,26} $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '&uniq.*.\{1,26\}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -E '&uniq.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,26}' ~/$f) == 0 ]; then echo
if [ $(grep -e '[&uniq.*]\{1,26}' $f) == 0 ]; then echo
done
```

Some examples of input:
Correct:
    &uniq._short_examples
    &uniq._ifs21t
    &uniq._FM_Z2IO_RHHU
    &uniq._kontr_save
Incorrect:
    &uniq.another_example_of_way_to_long_string
    &uniq.fhtygjygjyj767kjuhkhk87k8ukgfh56yhgyj76jujhyjk

Between this examples are some typical sql files lines like this:

```
SELECT  a.YY,
        a.RRX_ID,
        a.MSRG_TYPE,
        a.TGHSEB,
        a.PROVIDERHJJ,
        a.SALE_PROVIDERYTR,
        a.REQUEST_PPL,
        a.CONTENT_NAME, -- Name of content
        a.CONTENT_TYPE,  -- Name of content2
        b.NET_AMOUNT,
        a.SALE_MODEL_FROM_PAST,   
        a.SERVICE_MODE_ON,  
        a.RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE,
        a.ERROR_DESC_FILE
FROM    BBV.RAQ45_TJKIO a,
        (SELECT * from &uniq.FGGT8IO) b
```

Comment: No one is going to be able to tell what RE language you are talking about from just two examples.   You have to describe it more.  What exactly is valid, and what exactly is not valid, to a point where I could tell looking at an arbitrary string, unambiguously, if a sentence was in your language or not?

Comment: @Biffen -  I think the extraneous tags mean OP will accept a solution in any of those. (ie. he really means "regular expression")

Comment: Why are all your examples 1,26 if there can only be 21 characters after ?

Comment: @euro Are you expecting `grep` (on a *directory*!) to print `0`?! Your examples suggest you should probably start by reading some tutorials and/or manuals. e.g. `grep`'s and a shell scripting one.

Comment: @Biffen I think they intended to use it on the files inside.

Comment: Can you show an example of the string you are searching? E.g. does your `&uniq...` always end with a specific character?

Comment: The phrase &uniq consists of 5 signs. The whole phrase (which consist of &uniq + some other signs) may have maximum 26 signs, so after &uniq could be only 21 signs.

Comment: "What I want to do is to go through all the sql files and searching for phrase. " - and then do what?

Comment: So which ones from your sample input match and what does the rest of the line look like for each one? `grep` works on a line by line basis so the context is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using the following:

```
for f in /path/to/sql/files/*.sql; do
    if grep -q '&uniq.\{1,21\}' "$f"; then
        echo "match in file $f"
    fi
done
```

This matches "&uniq", followed by between 1 and 21 characters in any of the files in the directory `$f`. The `-q` switch to `grep` means that there is no output and the return code of grep indicates whether there was a match or not.

Presumably you also want to add some boundaries to either side of the pattern, so that you don't match things like `abc&uniqabc123abc123abc123 123456789`. The best way to do this depends on your input and the version of grep that you are using.

Judging by your example input, you could use the pattern `' &uniq.\{1,21\})'` to match the pattern with a space before and a closing `)` afterward.

Based on the extra info in the comments, it looks like you should change the pattern to something like `'&uniq\.[[:alnum:]]\{1,21\}[^[:alnum:]]'`, in order to match a literal dot after `&uniq`, between 1 and 21 alphanumeric characters, then any non-alphanumeric character.

Comment: Ok, I handled with that by using [a-zA-Z0-9_] instead [:alnum:]. Anyway Thank You very much Tom for all Your help!!! Have a nice weekend!

Comment: @euro no, keep `[:alnum:]` and add `_`, i.e. `[[:alnum:]_]`.